# Screen goes black after apk is signed

Tags: android, google-play

I have searched the internet for answers but found none of them.
So i sign my apk to put it on the store, as an update. When i start the application on my device the screen goes black. Any ideas ?

SplashScreen:

```
public class SplashScreen extends Activity implements ReadJSONFeedTaskListener {
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private int hasAckNoInternet = 0;
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private int hasAckNoTransferredData = 0;

public static void setAutoOrientationEnabled(ContentResolver resolver, boolean enabled) {
    Settings.System.putInt(resolver, Settings.System.ACCELEROMETER_ROTATION, enabled ? 1 : 0);
}

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {   
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    try {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);
        this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_LANDSCAPE);

        ProgressBar progressbar_ = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressbar_);
        TextView txtview_ = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.loadingprogress_);

        int i_notification_bar=MainShip.getInstance().get_I_from_shared_preferences("notification_bar");                
        if ( i_notification_bar==-1)
            MainShip.getInstance().save_to_shared_preferences_I("notification_bar", 0);

        int i_show_images_in_news=MainShip.getInstance().get_I_from_shared_preferences("images_in_news");
        if (i_show_images_in_news==-1)
            MainShip.getInstance().save_to_shared_preferences_I("images_in_news", 0);

        Integer i_default_play_quality=MainShip.getInstance().get_I_from_shared_preferences("default_play_quality");
        if ( i_default_play_quality<=0 )
            MainShip.getInstance().save_to_shared_preferences_I("default_play_quality",1);

        Integer i_show_images_in_movies=MainShip.getInstance().get_I_from_shared_preferences("images_in_movies");
        if ( i_show_images_in_movies<=0 )
            MainShip.getInstance().save_to_shared_preferences_I("images_in_movies",1);

        Integer i_no_wireless_warn=MainShip.getInstance().get_I_from_shared_preferences("no_wireless_warn");
        if ( i_no_wireless_warn<=0 )
            MainShip.getInstance().save_to_shared_preferences_I("no_wireless_warn",1);

        Integer i_permit_messages_from_server=MainShip.getInstance().get_I_from_shared_preferences("permit_messages_from_server");
        if ( i_permit_messages_from_server<=0 )
            MainShip.getInstance().save_to_shared_preferences_I("permit_messages_from_server",0);

        //delete logs
        SQLInterface oSQLInterface=new SQLInterface(this.getApplicationContext());
        oSQLInterface.delete_errors();
        oSQLInterface.close_database();

        //Log.e("MainShip","SplashScreen.onCreate -------------- called ----------------");
        new ReadJSONFeedTask(this, progressbar_, txtview_, this, this.getFilesDir().toString()).execute("executing readJSONFeedTask");
    } catch (Exception e) {  
        if ( e!=null )
            MainShip.getInstance().log_message(Log.getStackTraceString(e), true);   
    }

}

// This is the callback for when your async task has finished
@Override
public void onTaskFinished() {      
    completeSplash();
}

private void completeSplash(){
    startApp();
    finish(); // Don't forget to finish this Splash Activity so the user can't return to it!
}

private void startApp() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainScreen.class);
    startActivity(intent);

}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    return;
}
```

}

Comment: please paste your code

Comment: i'd the same, that was an issue with the paths of activities in the manifest. make sure to test your signed apk before sending :)

Comment: Make sure to add all your Activities to the manifest, add new permissions (if necessery), run the app after signing on your device(s) and not put it on the Market straight away.

Comment: @Hacketo everything looks normal

Comment: Check the onCreate of the Launching activity to find any intensive UI operation

Comment: When i try to export i have this error: Failed to export application
Command-line Error -1073741819

Comment: @Atrix1987 it's just a splash screen with a loading bar

Comment: @MarkusOlszewski checked the manifest, nothing that i have skipped there

Comment: can you please paste the code for splash screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have identified the error, it was the file proguard.cfg. After deleting it, all was good.